# Stop boost::io_service after certain amount of time

Tags: c++, boost

I have a boost::asio::io_service which is doing some work. Now I want to stop this service after a certain amount of time. My first approach was by using `boost::thread(io_service.run())`, but then I get errors.
Are there other ways to stop io_service?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `deadline_timer`.

You can also run the service on another thread like you tried:

```
boost::thread t = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, boost::ref(io_service));

// sometime
io_service.stop(); // io_service is threadsafe
t.join();
```

Here's a deadline_timer example complete in C++03: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7805b660469a2049)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost;

io_service svc;
deadline_timer timer(svc);

void work()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
    std::cout << "Work done, rescheduling\n";
    svc.post(work);
}

void expiration_handler(system::error_code ec)
{
    if (ec != error::operation_aborted)
        svc.stop();
}

int main()
{
    svc.post(work);

    timer.expires_from_now(posix_time::seconds(2));
    timer.async_wait(expiration_handler);

    svc.run();
}
```

This prints

```
Work done, rescheduling
```

until the deadline is reached after 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
io_service.stop();
```

Isn't it?

---

Use [deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html).

```
boost::asio::deadline_timer stop_timer(io_service);

...
// If require stopping
stop_timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
stop_timer.async_wait(
    [&io_service](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
    {
        io_service.stop();
    });
```

Comment: Nope. Because you're blocking on `io_service.run()`.

Comment: Yup that's more like it. My version doesn't require c++11 though

Comment: @sehe I love c++11 so much >o<